# Как убрать расстояние между картинками и сгруппировать текст с картинками?

Tags: html, frontend, css

Как убрать расстояние между картинками и сгруппировать текст с картинками так, как показано на скриншоте?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для img: `padding:0; margin:0;display:inline-block;`.
Для заголовка - так же.
Для параграфов: оба параграфа взять в один блок и задать ему `display: block;`.  Ну и для параграфа задать `display:inline-block;`.

Как-то так, но нужен ваш код, чтобы увидеть его визуально и ответить более конкретно, чтобы и вам же было менее хлопотно с редактированием. Много есть разных вариантов.

Comment: еще font-size: 0 нужен на случай whitespace'а между изображениями, помнится